# Creating an array by looping through a mySQL database, capturing entries only once in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database

i'm relatively new to coding and I need a little help. I'm basically trying to loop through an entry in a mySQL database and push any new entry into an array , so that it only comes up once in my array.

```
// SQL query 
$response = $bdd->query('SELECT serie_bd FROM inventaire_bd');


//creating array to group all elements from the db so that they do not repeat
$serie_bd_groupe=array();
while($data_collected = $response->fetch())
{   
    if(array_key_exists($data_collected,$serie_bd_groupe)==false)
    {
        array_push($data_collected,$serie_bd_groupe);
    }
}
```

Will this work? - it seems like the loop will just stay stuck after it comes accross an entry a second time because the if statement wont execute itself.

Also in the future, are their any php equivalent to jsfiddle.net so i can test code syntaxically?

Thank you for your time

Comment: `$data_collected` is fetched array or collector array?

Comment: Aside: `array_push` is a bad habit to get into. There are some very rare cases where you want to use it, but this is not one of them. Just use the `[]` operator.

Comment: @Jon out of my curiosity, why does it bad habit to use `array_push`? Is that because we can simply use `[]` operator? I can't see much difference than overhead of calling a function like the doc says.

Comment: @code-jaff: It's slower, and (more importantly) it's not idiomatic. Everyone immediately understands what `[]` does, while `array_push` requires the human reader to "parse" it.

Comment: In the manual it says "Note: If you use array_push() to add one element to the array it's better to use $array[] " http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array keys will be default integers, so you don't want to check those.  Instead of this:

```
if(array_key_exists($data_collected,$serie_bd_groupe)==false)
```

you should do this:

```
if(!(in_array($data_collected,$serie_bd_groupe)))
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

On the other hand, if you're expecting your collected data to be the array key rather than value, you'd do something like this, instead of your array_push:

```
$serie_bd_groupe[$data_collected] = 1;
```

then your key check would work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for UNIQUE values (serie_bd) from your database, update your query to include "DISTINCT" like this:

```
$bdd->query('SELECT DISTINCT serie_bd FROM inventaire_bd');
```

On the other hand, I think you are looking for http://phpfiddle.org/